# Trying to add address information like phone etc but only name, email and password get posted to DB

Tags: magento-1.9, database, model, ajax, register

The scenario : I am trying to register adress information such as phone, company name , etc via ajax using the youama ajax login/registration module. Right now only email, names, password seem to be posted. I am almost there but there must be doing something wrong in this the Model file: Ajaxregister.php

I took example from inchoo recent post: http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/

It says that it should use Mage::getModel('customer/address') for adress data, and not Mage::getModel('customer/customer').

However I tryed and it does not post any phone/company name in the DB.

Here is the code below:

```
class Youama_Ajaxlogin_Model_Ajaxregister
    extends Youama_Ajaxlogin_Model_Validator
{
    /**
     * Init.
     */
    public function _construct() 
    {
        parent::_construct();

        // Result for Javascript
        $this->_result = '';
        $this->_userId = -1;

        // Terms and conditions has been accepted
        if ($_POST['licence'] == 'ok') {
            $this->setEmail($_POST['email']);

            // If this email is already exist
            if ($this->isEmailExist()) {
                $this->_result .=  'emailisexist,';
            // If this email is not exist yet.
            } else {
                $this->setPassword($_POST['password'], $_POST['passwordsecond']);
                $this->setName($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname']);
                $this->setCompany($_POST['company']);
                $this->setTelephone($_POST['telephone']);
                $this->setNewsletter($_POST['newsletter']);

                // If there are no errors
                if ($this->_result == '') {
                    // Try register user

                    $this->_registerUser();

                    // Try subscribe user to newsletter
                    if ($this->_userNewsletter == true) {
                        $this->_subscribeUser();
                    }
                }
            }
        // Terms and conditions has not been accepted
        } else {
            $this->_result = 'nolicence,';
        }        
    }

    /**
     * Register user via Mage's API.
     */
    protected function _registerUser()
    {
        // Empty customer object
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
        $address->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

        // Set customer
        $customer->setEmail($this->_userEmail);
        $customer->setPassword($this->_userPassword);
        $customer->setFirstname($this->_userFirstName);
        $customer->setLastname($this->_userLastName);

        $address->setCompany($this->_userCompany);
        $address->setTelephone($this->_userTelephone);


        // Try create customer
        try {
            $customer->save();
            $address->save();
            $customer->setConfirmation(null);
            $customer->save();

            $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());

            $this->_userId = $customer->getId();

            $this->_result = 'success';
        // Error by injected HTML/JS
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $this->_result .= 'frontendhackerror,';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$address_data = array (
            'firstname' => 'fname here',
            'lastname' => 'lastname here',
            'street' => '123 test st',
            'city' => 'city here',
            ...
        );

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
// Set customer
$customer->setEmail($this->_userEmail);
$customer->setPassword($this->_userPassword);
...

$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$address->setData($address_data)
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('0')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

$customer->addAddress($address);

try {
    $customer->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    $this->_error($ex->getMessage());
    return;
}
```

---

You need to assign the customer id to the address

```
protected function _registerUser()
{
    .....

    // Try create customer
    try {


        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();
        if($customer->getId()){
           $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId()); 
           $address->save();
        }

        ...
```

See [Programmatically adding new customers to the Magento store](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/)

Comment: Thanks but I still have same problem, no data is inserted to database.

Comment: @user263286 ... take a look at my update

Comment: Thanks R . S , adress-related data gets inserted now. You rock :)

Answer (score 0):

**Issue1:** You need set `customer id` at  `customer address object` for set customer id to address

```
$customer->save();
/* add this code */
 $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
 $address->save();
```

Also for checking create address  validate for save  then try below code:

```
/* use to validate */
$valid = $address->validate();
if (!is_array($valid)) {
$address->save()
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I still have same problem, no data is inserted to database.

Comment: check $this->_userCompany.. etc give proper value at  _registerUser()

Comment: Thanks , I also tried with setData ( @R.S ) now it works